# Find string tag and replace with a hyperlink using SED

Tags: sed

New to SED and trying to use it to find a custom string tag and replace with an html hyperlink, but can't get the following SED format to work correctly. Thanks for your help.

**Summary:**
Find DEV-XXXX in string and replace w/ an html hyperlink, the DEV- string tag will always remain the same but the XXXX digit reference can vary for different strings.

`"This is a test of DEV-1212"`

`"This is a test of DEV-1213 more text"`

**Expected results:**

`"This is a test of <a href=\"https://devtest.net/DEV-1212\">DEV-1212</a>"`

`"This is a test of <a href=\"https://devtest.net/DEV-1215\">DEV-1213</a> more text"`

**This is the SED syntax I've been working with, but haven't been able to make it work correctly.**

`$ echo "This is a test DEV-1212" | sed -r 's/DEV-^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/<a href=\"https://devtest.net/&\">&</a>/'`

**Produces the following error. **
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s'

Comment: You are aware of of the concept of escaping sppecial characters. Try more of that for thsoe which are special to sed and `s` within sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from not escaping the `\/` when using `/` as the delimiter, your pattern does not match because the caret ^ asserts the start of the string which will not match.

```
DEV-^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*
----^
```

If there can only be digits after `DEV-` you could write the pattern as:

```
echo "This is a test of DEV-1212" | sed -r 's~DEV-[0-9]+~<a href="https://devtest.net/&">&</a>~'
```

Or else keep matching non digits and the rest of the line:

```
echo "This is a test of DEV-1212" | sed -r 's~DEV-[^0-9]*[0-9].*~<a href="https://devtest.net/&">&</a>~'
```

Output

```
This is a test of <a href="https://devtest.net/DEV-1212">DEV-1212</a>
```

**Edit**

If you want to match only digits:

```
echo "This is a test of DEV-1212 with more data" | sed -r 's~DEV-[^0-9]*[0-9]+~<a href="https://devtest.net/&">&</a>~'
```

Output

```
This is a test of <a href="https://devtest.net/DEV-1212">DEV-1212</a> with more data
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful! Currrently, I'm looking to only add the href to the DEV-XXXX in the string since there could be more text after the DEV-XXXX tag. For example, `"This is a test of DEV-1212 with more data"` and in this case I need the result string to be `"This is a test of <a href="https://devtest.net/DEV-1212">DEV-1212</a> with more data"` is it possible to filter out just the DEV-XXXX in the string and add the href markup just to that only? Currently, it adds any remaining text after the DEV-XXXX to the href. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bobparr I have updated the answer for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You did not escape `/`. Why escape `"`.

```
echo "This is a test DEV-1212" | sed -r 's/DEV-^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/<a href="https:\/\/devtest.net\/&">&<\/a>/'
```

but use a different delimieter:

```
echo "This is a test DEV-1212" | sed -r 's|DEV-^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*|<a href="https://devtest.net/&">&</a>|'
```